# Retrieve instantiated object from another method in the same class

Tags: php, symfony, object

Within the '*Default*' controller I have two method calls: '*SearchAction*' and '*DetailsSearchAction*' having their respective routes.

Well, '*SearchAction*' is responsible for returning an array of objects with the result of a search of houses with certain search parameters. So far no problem, I can get the list and display it on screen rendering a view.

For every house search listing is a link that should display details of that particular house, well, those details compulsorily must be obtained from the list obtained by '*SearchAction*', object already instantiated, so I need to pick up again the object created in the previous method call.

I do not know if I explained well, but could be **summarized** as within the same controller, I need to retrieve an instantiated object in a method in another method.

Comment: php does not have shared memory - all variables are destroyed at the end of each page request, so this is not possible. You could use caching, or a client side technique instead

Comment: I think you're looking for method chaining. Instead of returning the array, put it into a property of the class and return the class itself, using `$this`. After which you can chain your calls so you'd have something like this `$SearchAction()->DetailsSearchAction();`

Comment: So you have a page that list houses, the user clicks on one house and a new page is shown with details?  Just trying to make sure what you are asking for.